# Microsoft Excel as SQL Database

Tags: java, excel, odbc

I have followed the instructions provided in this [website from content 5.3](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JDBC_Basic.html#zz-5.3) and the code works fine.

My plan is to make a jar file (containing an interface/GUI), distribute that jar file to users, and then have them all read/write data should be from one excel file. When I place the excel file in local drive it works, but when I place the file in network folder/server, the java creates a problem:

> java.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry
>   for the inconvenience.

or

```
Java Result: -1073741811
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

```
public class TestIntoExcel 
{
public String s;
public double number;
public Date d;
public void display()throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection writeConnection = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:odbc:usersavedataODBC");
    writeConnection.setReadOnly(false);
    Statement writeStatement = writeConnection.createStatement();
    writeStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE TEST_INSERT(COL1 INT,COL2 VARCHAR(10),COL3 DATE)");
    PreparedStatement writeStatement2 = 
        writeConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TEST_INSERT(COL1,COL2,COL3)VALUES(?,?,?)");

    for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
    {
        writeStatement2.setDouble(1, i);
        writeStatement2.setString(2, "Row" + i);
        writeStatement2.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime()));
        writeStatement2.execute();
     }

    String query = "select *from[TEST_INSERT]";
    ResultSet rset = writeStatement.executeQuery(query);
    //System.out.println(rset);
    while(rset.next())
    {
        number = rset.getDouble("COL1");
        s = rset.getString("COL2");
        d = rset.getDate("COL3");
        System.out.println(number+"\n"+s+"\n"+d);
}

writeStatement.close();
writeStatement2.close();
writeConnection.close();
```

Comment: Could be lots of things that. Check you can open it with excel first. PS is this readonly. If you are writing back to the excel file, the wheels are going to come off quick.

Comment: As I mentioned above, If I save the file in local drive everything is fine to read/write from program and view in excel, but when I try to do same time by placing the excel file in network folder, I will recieve the java.exe error and the excel file is empty.

Comment: Are you performing any writes ?

Comment: Can you read and write to the remote file from Excel itself ?

Comment: just a min, I will update my question with code

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean remote file? yes I am performance writes.

Comment: Not what I said, when you put it on the network drive, will excel read it.  Given you code works locally, it's more likely to be an issue with the driver, or the connection string. Can't help you there, if I did this I'd get the sack.